# Reduction formula.

Tags: calculus

> For definite integration, we have $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^nx\,dx=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{n-3}{n-2}\cdot\dfrac{n-5}{n-4}\cdots\dfrac{2}{3}&\textrm{when}\ n\ \textrm{is odd}\\\dfrac{n-1}{n}\cdot\dfrac{n-3}{n-2}\cdot\dfrac{n-5}{n-4}\cdots\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac\pi2&\textrm{when}\ n\ \textrm{is even}.
> \end{array}\right.$$

For n = even for sine function definite integral we have a formula, but in the case of n =2(even), n-2 would give 0, which would result in the product of all the terms in the denominator to be zero, which would result in pi/0, which i think is wrong. So i want to know what happens in case of n =2.

Comment: When writing something like $n\times (n-2)\times (n-4)\times\cdots\times 2$ for $n$ even that is shorthand for $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n/2}(2k)$, which is also notated $n!!$.  You have that $2!!=2,~~ 4!!=4\times 2 = 8,~~ 6!!=6\times 4\times 2 = 48,~~ 8!!=8\times 6\times 4\times 2 =\dots$ and so on... It is also worth pointing out $0!!=1$, as $0!!$ is treated as the empty product.

Comment: It doesnt answer my doubt, we have sin^2 thus n =2, when we put n=2 in the formula, 0 appears in denominator and that is causing a problem in my thought process..

Comment: $0$ doesn't appear in a denominator though.  The $n-2$ in $n\times (n-2)\times (n-4)\times \cdots \times 2$ might not have actually occurred.  The first few terms there are only there in order to show the pattern.  The pattern being that the terms in the product change by $2$ each step and we multiply them all together, the largest term in the product being $n$ and the smallest term in the product being $2$.  Here, with $n=2$, the largest term in the product being $2$ and the smallest term in the product being $2$, we have that the entire product itself is simply $2$

Comment: Is it frustrating for beginners?  Yes, you aren't the first person to be confused by this.  Is it ambiguous notation?  Arguably, yes.  It is particularly frustrating to get across that the number of terms in the product $n\times (n-2)\times (n-4)\times \cdots \times 2$ might be less than four since we can clearly see four of the potentially many terms in the product as written, but the notation is there only to suggest the pattern and to adjust it as necessary in the case that we need fewer terms in the product than that.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 1):

Focus on this part:  $$\frac{n-1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-3}{n-2}\cdot\frac{n-5}{n-4}\cdots\frac{1}{\color{blue}{2}}\frac\pi2.$$

Start counting from the right.  Notice that you reach a denominator of $\color{blue}2$ right away.  So the answer would just be $\dfrac\pi2$.

More simply, if you have a series $n, n-2, n-4,\ldots, 2$, this does not mean to substitute for $n$ wherever you see $n$, but to *count down* until you reach $2$.  Since you are at $2$ already, you are done.

Comment: Why we dont put n=2 ?

Comment: You ignore those factors since you are already _at_ $2$.

Comment: Try this exercise:  count down to $1$ from $5$.  You would think that the sequence is $5, 5-1, 5-2, \cdots, 1$.  Now count down to $1$ from $1$.  Does it make sense if you write it as $1, 1-1, 1-2, \cdots, 1$?

Comment: So that means we use the "n" variable part only for n != 2?

Comment: You use the variable $n$ as necessary.  $n(n-2)(n-4)\cdots2$ means to count down even numbers _until you get to $2$_.  Since you are already at $2$, there is no need to use the part preceding.  Similarly, if you were to use $4$, you would simply use $n(n-2)$, since by the time you reach $n-2$, you will have already reached $2$.